# Db2 zos update set of values in tables

Tags: db2, sql-update, zos

There are set of values to update. Example: table t1 has column c1 which has to be updated from 1 to x. There are around 300 such sets available in a file and around 15 such tables with over 100k of records.

What is the optimal way of doing this?

Approaches I can think of are:

- individual update statement for old with new value in all tables
- programmatically read the file and create dynamic update statement
- using merge into table syntax

In one of the tables the column is primary key with tables referencing them as foreign key

Comment: "Optimal" according to what criteria?

Comment: Lesser update statements and faster updates